# Add condition based on result of str_replace operation

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to check if str_replace is working while looping.

I am adding condition with `str_replace $count` as seen below, but this works for first string only.

It can be a condition before or after str_replace starts. I may be missing something and I'm not very good at looping.

```
<?php
   
   $text = array( 'text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5' );
   
   $text = implode( ' ', $text );
   
   $maps = array(
     
     // keys and value
     array_fill_keys( array( 'text1' ), 'replaces1' ),
     
     array_fill_keys( array( 'text2' ), 'replaces2' ),
     
     array_fill_keys( array( 'text3' ), 'replaces3' ),
   
   );
   
   foreach( $maps as $map ) {
       foreach( $map as $key => $value ) {
   
          $text = str_replace( $key, $value, $text, $count );
       
     }
   }
       
   if( $count == 0 ) {
       
       $text = '.Yeni>'.$text;
       
   }

   return $text;

?>
```

**Output;**

```
// Here only the first string is fine, the `if($count == 0)` condition after it means nothing, with or without replace.
replaces1 .Yeni>replaces2 .Yeni>replaces3 .Yeni>text4 .Yeni>text5
```

**Expected output;**

```
replaces1 replaces2 replaces3 .Yeni>text4 .Yeni>text5
```

**UPDATE FOR SOLVED**

All I needed was `array_column`. That way, I checked `$map` for `$text` before the loop and transformation started, if not needed the loop and transformation didn't start at all.

```
<?php
   
   $text = array( 'text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5' );
   
   $text = implode( ' ', $text );
   
   $maps = array(
     
     // keys and value
     array_fill_keys( array( 'text1' ), 'replaces1' ),
     
     array_fill_keys( array( 'text2' ), 'replaces2' ),
     
     array_fill_keys( array( 'text3' ), 'replaces3' ),
   
   );
   
   if( array_column( $maps, $text )  ) {
   
      foreach( $maps as $map ) {
   
       $text = str_replace( array_keys( $map ), array_values( $map ), $text, $count );
       
      }
   }else {
       
       $text = '.Yeni>'.$text;
       
     }

   return $text;

?>
```

**Now Output;**

```
replaces1 replaces2 replaces3 .Yeni>text4 .Yeni>text5
```

Comment: Here's a [slimmed down version](https://3v4l.org/1Iqpi) of your code which shows that `str_replace` is in fact working since it is only looking for `text1`, `text2` and `text3`. I'm not really clear on what isn't working? `text4` is never searched for so it will never result in a `count` of zero.

Comment: I want to add `.Yeni>` only `text4` and `text5` but it is appended to all but the first string. I Need to check every `$count` in all `str_replace strings` for it to work properly. Or there could be another method.

Comment: Yes, `$text = '.Yeni>'.$text;` means append. You are not searching for `text4` in anyway. If you don't tell the search system what to look for, it can't tell you if it exists or not. Do you instead want to scan all the words to see if they are in the main array?

Comment: Yes I tried but failed because I am not good with directories. Is it possible for us to check the home directory before the `loop` and `str_replace`?

Comment: The posted question says nothing about directories, so I'm not sure how that relates

Comment: Checking `$text` and `$maps` arrays before `str_replace` might actually be a solution, but I don't know whether to do it as an index or as a string.

Comment: Can you edit your question with what you want the final output to look like?

Comment: I updated, the reason I want `array_fill_keys` is because I need to use multiple `keys`. Maybe `array_fill_keys` can be compared to `$text` strings.

Comment: If you think each "thing" is a bunch of characters separated by a space you could [explode based on that](https://3v4l.org/l397f). But if your real text also has punctuation marks or other things you might run into trouble

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this will not be the solution unfortunately.

Comment: Instead of framing the question are you current have, which is generally what we recommend, can you instead reword it as you have input _XYZ_, you want to do _ABC_ which includes data from _QWE_ and you expect output _TBD_. Also, can you explain why `replaces1 replaces2 replaces3 .Yeni>text4 text5` _isn't_ valid? In that version I replaced the thing `text4 text5` with `.Yeni>text4 text5`. You say that `text4` and `text5` are separate things, but you need to quantify why they are.

Comment: One solution would be to compare the strings in `$maps` with the string `$text` before starting the loop. This way the loop never starts and `str_replace` is not needed.

Comment: If you have a solution that you find acceptable, even if you wrote it, please write it as an answer and accept it, that is totally fine. That said, your code as posted doesn't show what you say you expected to receive: https://3v4l.org/Q8CGZ

Answer (score 1):

$count variable always equals to 1 in your current situation because in every foreach loop str_replace() function was altering only one element. So, you cannot say that if count is zero do a some process beacuse if count is zero, it leads to "Fatal error".